# Unable to send mail using gmail api node js

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-apis-explorer

I have followed [gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) for sending email. I am getting error as:

> "message": "400 - \"{\n \\"error\\": {\n  \\"errors\\": [\n   {\n    \\"domain\\": \\"global\\",\n    \\"reason\\": \\"invalidArgument\\",\n    \\"message\\": \\"'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required\\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \\"code\\": 400,\n  \\"message\\": \\"'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required\\"\n }\n}\n\""

Here is the piece of code I have written for sending mail using gmail api with node.js. Help me out to resolve the issue.

```
router.post('/composeMail', async (req, res, next) => {
    function makeBody(to, from, subject, message) {
        let str = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n",
            "Content-length: 5000\n",
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: message/rfc822\n",
            "to: ", to,"\n",
            "from: ", from,"\n",
            "subject: ", subject,"\n\n",
            message
        ].join('');
        console.log("String: ", str);
        // let encodedMail = new Buffer(str).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
        let encodedMail = btoa(str).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
        return encodedMail;
    }
    let raw = makeBody("dinesh.kumar@gmail.com", "dinesh.kumar@gmail.com", "Test mail", "Everything is fine");
    let obj = {};
    obj.raw = raw;
    let body = JSON.stringify(obj);
    let option = {
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send",
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${req.query.access_token}`
        },
        qs: {
            userId: 'me'
        },
        body: body
    };

    await request(option).then(body => {
        return res.apiOk(body);
    }).catch(err => {
        return res.apiError(err);
    })
});
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Yes your answer worked for me @Tanaike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to send an email using Gmail API by the request module.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points:

- Please use `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send` as the endpoint.
- Use the value as a string.
- Add `'Content-Type': 'message/rfc822'` to the headers.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `makeBody()` as follows.

```
function makeBody(to, from, subject, message) {
    let str = [
        "to: ", to, "\n",
        "from: ", from, "\n",
        "subject: ", subject, "\n\n",
        message,
    ].join('');
    return str;
}
```

Please modify `option` as follows.

```
let raw = makeBody("dinesh.kumar@gmail.com", "dinesh.kumar@gmail.com", "Test mail", "Everything is fine");
const userId = 'me'; // Please modify this for your situation.
let option = {
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/" + userId + "/messages/send",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${req.query.access_token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'message/rfc822',
    },
    body: raw,
};
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that Gmail API is enabled at API console and the required scope for sending emails is included in the scopes of access token.

#### Reference:

- [Users.messages: send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

In my environment, I could confirm that this modified script worked fine. But if this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Dinesh Sathrasala I'm sorry. I cannot understand about your comment. Can you post it as new question including more information? When you post it, it will help users including me think of your issue.

Comment: Tanaike please check the link of my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53761566/reply-to-a-mail-is-not-showing-in-thread-for-sender-of-mail-but-it-is-showing-in

Comment: @Dinesh Sathrasala Thank you for replying. I would like to check it.

Comment: I have found solution for it. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Dinesh Sathrasala Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Tanaike How to send attachments in mail using above api

Comment: @Dinesh Sathrasala I'm sorry. In order to understand correctly your new question, can you post it as new question including more information? When you post it, it will help users think of about your new question.

Comment: Tanaike please see this issue. This is url of my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886947/email-with-attachment-is-not-going-properly