# Invalid arguments when sending basic email through GMail API

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I'm trying to send an email via the Gmail API through a Google Apps Script in Sheets using the example from the Gmail API Documentation, but I'm getting an:

> Exception: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-4 only (line 240, file "Code").

`Line 240` is when I call `Gmail.Users.Messages.send`. This looks to be the most basic email message I can construct. Can someone help me with what I'm missing?

```
function senDAMail() {

  var bdy =  "From: steve@gmail.com\n\r, To: steve@gmail.com\n\r, Subject: test\n\r\n\r, You first build the message with headers like From and Subject as you mentioned, but you have to encode the message before sending it. There is no way around that.";

  var encodemsg = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(bdy);

  Gmail.Users.Messages.send({
    auth: this.oAuth2Client,
    'userId': 'steve@gmail.com',
    'resource': {
      'raw': encodemsg
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Please remove `,` of `\n\r, To`, `\n\r, Subject` and `\n\r\n\r, YouP`.
- Please replace `\n\r` to `\r\n` or only `\n`.
- The arguments of `Gmail.Users.Messages.send(resource, userId)` are `resource, userId`.

  - In your case, I think that `resource` and `userId` are `{raw: encodemsg}` and `"me"`, respectively.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function senDAMail() {
  var bdy =  "From: steve@gmail.com\nTo: steve@gmail.com\nSubject: test\n\nYou first build the message with headers like From and Subject as you mentioned, but you have to encode the message before sending it. There is no way around that.";
  var encodemsg = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(bdy);
  Gmail.Users.Messages.send({raw: encodemsg}, "me");
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Users.messages: send](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike, thank you, this worked. Do you have a current resource for the Gmail API that's perhaps not maintained by Google? I've been through the link you referenced above several times and none of their examples or explanations have been clear enough for me to construct an email successfully. The API calls they make aren't even correct or outdated. I happened upon an error message one day that allowed me to blindly debug it down to Gmail.Users.Messages.send.

Comment: @vaportrailfacilities Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the sample resource, I posted my answer by checking the sample script in [this document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send). For example, in this case, I checked the sample script of python. And also, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53263239/7108653) might be also useful. But if this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.